# SQL with calculation from 2 tables's sum

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables `Sales` and `return` and i have two queries to get each day sales total and return total of certain month. it's result like this.

```
SELECT strftime('%m/%d', Date) as valDay, SUM(TotalPrice) as valTotal FROM Sales WHERE strftime('%m', Date) ='12' GROUP BY valDay;
```

Result

```
valDay  valTotal
12/01   50.0
12/02   50.0
12/04   50.0
12/05   120.0
12/06   160.0
12/07   30.0
12/08   80.0
12/09   50.0
```

and the second query is

```
SELECT strftime('%m/%d', Date) as valDay, SUM(TotalPrice) as valTotal FROM return WHERE strftime('%m', Date) ='12' GROUP BY valDay;
```

Result

```
valDay  valTotal
12/01   10.0
12/05   100.0
12/08   20.0
```

I want to deduct each day return total from same day sales. the result should be like this, ignore the brackets btw

```
valDay  valTotal
12/01   40.0 (50-10)
12/02   50.0
12/04   50.0
12/05   20.0 (120 - 100)
12/06   160.0
12/07   30.0
12/08   60.0 (80 - 20) 
12/09   50.0
```

is it possible to do with a single query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `UNION ALL` to get the resultset that includes all the rows of the 2 tables that you want and then aggregate only once:

```
SELECT strftime('%m/%d', Date) valDay, SUM(TotalPrice) valTotal
FROM (
  SELECT Date, TotalPrice 
  FROM Sales 
  WHERE strftime('%m', Date) ='12'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Date, -TotalPrice  -- here you get the negative TotalPrice of the column
  FROM return
  WHERE strftime('%m', Date) ='12'
)
GROUP BY valDay
```

If you have data that expand to more than 1 year and all you want is the results for all Decembers of all years then this query will work.

But if you want the results for a particular year then you should also include the year in the `WHERE` clause, like:

```
WHERE strftime('%Y/%m', Date) = '2020/12'
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is `union all` and aggregation:

```
SELECT valDay, SUM(sales) - SUM(returns)
FROM (SELECT strftime('%m/%d', s.Date) as valDay, SUM(s.TotalPrice) as sales, 0 as returns
      FROM Sales s
      WHERE strftime('%m', s.Date) = '12'
      GROUP BY valDay
      UNION ALL
      SELECT strftime('%m/%d', r.Date) as valDay, 0, SUM(r.TotalPrice) as valTotal
      FROM return r
      WHERE strftime('%m', r.Date) = '12'
      GROUP BY valDay
     ) sr
GROUP BY valDay
```

Comment: can' figure out why but it gives me a error `Result: near ";": syntax error At line 1:`

Comment: After the first `group by` you need to remove the `;` and you will resolve that error

Answer (score 1):

Simply, use the `LEFT JOIN` between two of your query and use the expression to calculate the result as follows:

```
select s.valDay, s.valTotal -r.valTotal from
(SELECT strftime('%m/%d', Date) as valDay, SUM(TotalPrice) as valTotal FROM Sales WHERE strftime('%m', Date) ='12' GROUP BY valDay) s
left join
(SELECT strftime('%m/%d', Date) as valDay, SUM(TotalPrice) as valTotal FROM return WHERE strftime('%m', Date) ='12' GROUP BY valDay) r
on s.valDay = r.valDay
```

Comment: There may be dates that exist in `return` but not in `Sales`. By doing this LEFT join you ignore all these rows.

Comment: Yes. We should ignore that. It is expected, I think.